# The "Compare and Pull Request" button on github does not remember/respect the selected branch?

Tags: github

After a push from a local git clone to *github* there is a (nominally) helpful message

> "{branch-name} had recent pushes {N} minutes ago"

Here is an example. Notice that the currently selected branch is **feature/dev**
:

[image]

So I clicked on the *Compare & pull request* . Unfortunately the resulting PR is against **Master** :

[image]

That's a bug IMO.  Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. The default branch for a pull request and the message you see is not related to whatever branch your gui is currently looking at. In settings, you can change the default pull request target branch (i.e. set it to "develop" instead of "master").

Comment: And of course you can change the target branch of a PR, if you need to. But most of the time, PRs will be against the same branch.

Comment: @PMF  Thanks for that info about changing the default pull request target: I did just change that in settings.    I retain my opinion on the behavior being sup-optimal: it effectively makes the button only marginally  useful since for our project we use a number of different branches and the "default" is only going to be correct a fraction of the time no matter what it is set to.

Comment: I see. That is (as far as I can tell) a bit a rare situation. Normally, you create PRs only to a specific branch (typically master) and after they have landed, you merge them over to different branches (if needed).

Comment: @PMF  We manage differences across different geographical regions and deployment environments within those regions that drive CI/CD pipelines. In addition there are several quite distinct groups (FE/BE/ AI-ML) .  There are reasons we have not divided into multiple repositories - which would reduce the branches diversity to an extent.